# BeautifulSoup find_all Method not Generalising

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, urlopen

I'm a bit stuck on a problem with BeautifulSoup. This piece of code is a snippet from a function I'm trying to debug. The scraper worked fine and suddenly stopped. The strange thing is that the class I'm searching for "ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid" is in the "post_soup" file that is produced in the second step of the loop.

As part of my debugging, I wanted to see what was produced which is the reason for the text file. However, it is empty. I have no idea why.

Any ideas?

```
post_pages = ['https://coffeeforums.co.uk/topic/4843-a-little-thank-you/', 'https://coffeeforums.co.uk/topic/58690-for-sale-area-rules-changes-important/']

for topic_url in post_pages:
    post_page = urlopen(topic_url)
    post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_page, 'lxml')
    messy_posts = post_soup.find_all('div',  class_='ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid')
    with open('messy_posts.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(messy_posts))
```

edit: you can swap in this variable to see how it should work. These websites are built on the same platform so the scrape should be the same (I would think):

```
post_pages = ['https://forum.cardealermagazine.co.uk/topic/8603-customer-comms-and-the-virus/', 'https://forum.cardealermagazine.co.uk/topic/10096-volvo-issue-heads-up/']
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Try with css selectorr it will work because space it does not find desired outptut

Answer (score 0):

The class_ takes a list for multiple classes and not a string for an OR operation. You could change it from

```
 class_='ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid'
```

it to this and it should work.

```
class_=['ipsColumn', 'ipsColumn_fluid']
```

and it should work.

Alternatively, if you are going for an AND(where you want a div with both classes). I advise you to use `select` as such:

```
post_soup.select('div.ipsColumn.ipsColumn_fluid')
```

This would return the div that includes both classes

Comment: That is not true. `class_='ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid'` is completely fine if OP wants to exactly match the string value of a HTML tag's class attribute. Your proposed change `class_=['ipsColumn', 'ipsColumn_fluid']` uses a logical OR filter, i.e. matches `class='ipsColumn'`, `class='ipsColumn_fluid'` or`class='ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid`.